# "a cut of a video" vs. "a clip of a video"

Tags: word-usage

In some situations, it's more intuitive/expressive/impressive to put some videos in a presentation to explain how things work.

Assume I'm giving a presentation and trying to get attention of audience. Would I say

> I’m gonna play a **clip** of a video.

or

> I’m gonna play a **cut** of a video.

Which one is more clear and natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the word “clip” is much more idiomatic.

Also, I think the word “cut” signifies a more permanent “clipping” of the video, e.g., a “director’s cut”, which is released as a different product.